# angularjs how to handle $stateParams variables after a reload of page

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how i should keep $stateParams variables after a reload of page.

```
.state('proSearch', {
                    url: '/proSearch/:city',
                    params: {
                        location: null
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'imports/client/ui/proSearch/proSearch.html',
                    controller: 'proSearchController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                })
```

When the page is reloaded my controller has lost $stateParams.location data. How can i save it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can reach it in the controller with $stateParams service.

```js
function MainController($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

 
    var city = $stateParams.location
    
    state.go($state.current, {location: city}, {reload: true});

}
```

This code is keep your location params at the city variable and second row is refresh the page with current city parameter. I hope it's help

Comment: I'm talking about location params that contains coordinates information. It s not pass through url and get lost after reloading the page.

Comment: Actually I couldn't get what you want exactly but I update my code snippet for update current page with current parameters @Youssef

Answer (score 0):

You can save the $stateParams data on a $scope variable instead of a local variable. A $scope variable persists on your scope.

```
$scope.city = $stateParams.location;
```

You can access $scope variables on other controllers, as long as you reference $scope.

I guess you don't need to reload the page. Two-way data binding is a cool concept that encourages not having to reload a page to see data update.

Comment: the problem is if the user refresh the page the scope is also cleaned. My issue : A user have done a research and wrongly refresh his/her page i would like to keep displaying correct data. However location variable is not pass by url.